# trying to sort a list with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I've got this code that I've pieced together where I'm trying to sort a list, at least that's what I'm trying to do:

```
List<TagLib.File> listOfFiles = new List<TagLib.File>();
foreach (string file in files)
{
   TagLib.File fi = TagLib.File.Create(file);
   listOfFiles.Add(fi);
}

System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<TagLib.File> pleaseSort
    = listOfFiles.OrderBy(x => x.Tag.AlbumArtists)
                 .ThenBy(x => x.Tag.Album);

foreach (TagLib.File tl in pleaseSort)
{
    ...
}
```

The line that  begins with

```
System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable
```

lets the program go past it but then in the for each line stepping through the code it goes back to the IOrderedEnumerable and that is where I get the following error:

> -2147024809 at least one object must implement IComparable

I'll be the first to admit that I'm no expert, this is just a pet project I'm working on, but I can't find any documentation that clearly explains what I should be looking to do in this instance. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is `x.Tag.AlbumArtists`?

Comment: Either `x.Tag.AlbumArtists` or `x.Tag.Album` (or both) does not implement `IComparable`.  Clearly, `AlbumArtists` is some sort of list.  So, when you say you want to order the files by `AlbumArtists`, are you able to explain, logically, how you expect the sorting to work?  What would it sort by exactly?

Comment: Try this :             List<TagLib.File> pleaseSort
                  = listOfFiles.OrderBy(x => x.Tag.AlbumArtists).ThenBy(x => x.Tag.Album).ToList();

Comment: to be honest, the x came from another post I was reading about this. the tag.album and tagalbumartists are tags from mp3 files. So this list is a list that I'm wanting to sort by the artists first then by the album then I would like to loop through the list and do some stuff with the other tags. I hope that's enough info to render more help. Thanks.

Comment: @Brendon: It would be useful if you share with us what the exact types are for `AlbumArtists` and `Album`. But backto the point I was trying to make earlier, if each file has more than one artist, what does sorting by a *list of* artists actually mean?  For example, do you sort by the name of the *first* artist in the list, or do you expect some other logic?

Answer (score 3):

By doing a little digging in the source for [Tag.cs](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp/blob/master/src/TagLib/Tag.cs), which appears to be what you are using (it would have been nice to provide that information, it's hard to guess), I can see that `AlbumArtists` is defined as an array of strings (`string[]`).  That's where the problem is coming from.

Arrays don't implement `IComparable`.  And, if you think about it, it makes sense.  If you have 2 arrays, which one should sort ahead of the other?  What are the sorting rules?  Do you sort on the first item of each array, on the last, or do you apply some other sorting logic?  There are no clear rules for how to sort arrays, and so cannot be automatically determined by the .NET Framework, thus resulting in the error you got.

Basically, to make this work, the burden is on you to define how to sort `AlbumArtists` arrays from different tags.  You can do that by calling the overloaded [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422(v=vs.110).aspx) method where you get to specify your own implementation of an [IComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx).

Or, say you want the sort to be based on the *first* element of the `AlbumArtists` array, then you can change the code to only access that first element (which *is* comparable), and it should work fine (as long as every tag has at least one album artist in the array of course):

```
listOfFiles.OrderBy(x => x.Tag.AlbumArtists[0]) // access the first item only.
             .ThenBy(x => x.Tag.Album);
```